# Email Space usage too much

Tags: ipad, email, settings

Why does my iPad 2 version 7.1.2 show mail usage 1.4 GB when I have only four emails in all boxes? I have erased all mail from my computer mailboxes also...

Comment: Where is the Usage shown? In iTunes on your Mac?

Comment: Did you configure your Mail-Account as an IMAP- or to a POP-Account?

Comment: A pop account...

Answer (score 1):

Please check:

- If you start the Mail.app, you get a list of Shortcuts (in the upper
  left corner)
- Below that you should see a list of your accounts. If
  you click on one of your accounts, you get a list of all your
  Folders/Mailboxes (i hope i translated it correctly).
- Check if the Trash-Folder is empty or if there are still Mails marked for
  deletion.
- Repeat that for all your Mailaccounts and check other Folders like the  'Draft'-Folder too.

Alternative Option: If you have all Mail-Account Credentials, delete all Accounts and re-create them. Perhaps that will change the Usage. Please check before re-creating them.

Comment: Thanks JC, I had already done that...that's why I'm dumbfounded about the 1,4 GB! But thanks for answering

Comment: Hi Anna. I have added an alternative approach in my answer.